# Axios promise will never resolve

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, promise, axios

For the life of me, I can **never** get my Axios.post promise to resolve.

I know that my front end and backend are perfectly connected.

Try/catch blocks to return the resolved promise haven't worked either.

No matter what I do, I can never get inside of my promise.then() function. What am I doing incorrectly in my backend file?

CODE THAT HASN'T WORKED TO RESOLVE THE PROMISE

```
async handleDateSubmit() {
    let resolvedPromise = await Axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3001/get_number_of_dates_from_email",
        {
            email: this.state.user_email_m
        }
    );

    resolvedPromise
        .then(response => {
            //I can never get to here.
            console.log("Made it inside");
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

//---attempt two----//
async getResolvedPromise() {
    try {
        return await Axios.post(
            "http://localhost:3001/get_number_of_dates_from_email",
            {
                email: this.state.user_email_m
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async handleDateSubmit() {
    let resolvedPromise = this.getResolvedPromise();

    //work with resolvedPromsie
}
```

CURRENT CODE

```
//------------send_info.js front end file----------//
handleDateSubmit() {
    Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/get_number_of_dates_from_email', {
        email: this.state.user_email_m
    })
    .then((response) => {
        //I can never get to here.
        console.log("Made it inside");
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

//---------------server.js backend file---------------//
router.route('/get_number_of_dates_from_email').post(function (req, res) {
    //"user_email" is correct in my schema model and "req.body.email" is always what it should be
    User.findOne({ user_email: req.body.email }, (err, foundUser) => {
        console.log("Inside of findOne()");

        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            let numDates = foundUser.dates_list.length;

            //I always get here and numDates is always correct
            console.log("Number of dates: ", numDates);
            return res.json({ "numDates": numDates }); //Should I be using res.send()? 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're confusing promises and resolved promises at times in your code

```
// Attempt one
async handleDateSubmit() {
    try {
        let resolvedPromise = await Axios.post(
            "http://localhost:3001/get_number_of_dates_from_email",
            {
                email: this.state.user_email_m
            }
        );
        // Here resolvedPromise as stated by its name is not a promise anymore, thus you can't use .then()
        // You can directly work with resolvedPromise as it contains the response.

    }   catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }
 }

// Attempt two
async getResolvedPromise() {
    try {
        // Here you're returning the resolved promise, but the async await syntax turn your function into an AsyncFunction object
        // This type of function will wrap the return value in a promise if it's not one
        return await Axios.post(
            "http://localhost:3001/get_number_of_dates_from_email",
            {
                email: this.state.user_email_m
            }
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

async handleDateSubmit() {
    // Thus you need to await the result of your function 
    let resolvedPromise = await this.getResolvedPromise();
}
```